# 18.04 LTS won't let me re-login and shut down after failed apt get update

Tags: apt, login

The machine was pretty slow already. However I decided to execute `sudo apt-get update`.

However the update stopped at 90% updating some trigger.

So I decided to log out and re login with user. However the system didn't let me log on any more.

So I decided to log on with an alternative user and triggered the update again, same message:

```
Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?
```

Then I tried a shutdown. Now I just see the Ubuntu logo and white/red dots moving from left to right.

This machine is important for me, what's the best thing to do for me now?

Should I just switch off power and reboot?

Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you do `apt-get update` or `apt-get upgrade`? The `update` shouldn't modify anything that could broke your system, it just updates `apt`/`dpkg` indices and caches.

Comment: apt-get update. Is there a possibility to switch from splash screen to comand line to see shutdown? Or should I just turn off? (Shutdown now already takes many many minutes)

Answer (score 0):

1) List apt process

```
ps -A | grep apt
```

this show like output:

```
12421 pts/1 00:00:00 apt
12445 pts/1 00:00:00 apt
```

2) Kill this process:
The process ID (PID) is found in the first column from the output above.

```
sudo kill -SIGKILL <PID>
```

3) Remove Lock

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: Because ctrl alt F1/F2 didn't let me log in I decided to switch off power.  When I rebooted   Luckily after reboot everything was fine. And btw: the command I executed was 'sudo apt upgrade' (I wanted to do updates but without any new kernels etc.)